# CSS relative position with right side relative to viewport

Tags: html, css

I have several divs, each a child of the previous. They're all positioned `relative`, so that I can offset the children relative to the parents. I want to have the right sides line up, but I can't figure out how. Doing `width: 100%` obviously doesn't work because it ignores that the divs are not at `left: 0`.

As you can see, the divs escape the viewport:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: #4286f4;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: #3267bc;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: #244a87;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <div id="div3">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you prefer: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tc82z39s/1/)

How can I position the right side of each div at some specific distance from the right side of the screen with only CSS?

This is the expected output (the black rectangle around the outside represents the edges of the screen):

[image]

Comment: can you please share screenshot of desired output

Comment: You have each div at 50px from left, with width 100%... it has to go 50px off the viewport doesn't it? And each div 50px further from the last?

Comment: @NitinDaddikar Good point, added.

Comment: @Bman70 Well yes, but how? I don't know of a way to get the current left position relative to the viewport in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using `margin-left` instead of `left`.

With the [CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) default, "width and height properties include the content, but *does not include the padding, border, or margin*," ([box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)).

Also, block-level elements take up "the full width available", so `width:100%` isn't necessary ([Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)).

```css
body {
  margin: 20px 60px 20px 20px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

div div {
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: #4286f4;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: #3267bc;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: #244a87;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <div id="div3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does what I want, thanks! Not sure exactly _why_ this works, but it does... will have to think about it some more to understand how it works. Also, while I currently don't need to do this, is there a way to increase the gap on the right side? Just thinking that may become a requirement in future.

Comment: I added some explanation. Do you mean a gap between the boxes and the right side of the window?

Comment: You're right about not needing `width: 100%`. My mistake. I started with `width: 500px` during testing and forgot that I could just remove it to make the boxes try to fill the maximum area. And yes, the gap between the boxes and the right side of the window.

Comment: Depending on the context, I might add that space to the container. In my example, that's the `<body>`. I edited my example to reflect that.

Comment: Oh true, of course! Thanks! This was a nightmarish thing to try to google for so I'm glad you were able to answer my question so quickly after I finally resorted to asking :D